# Related Projects (Structure + Channel Matrix)

Tags: matrix, structure

I've looked around a good bit to see if I could solve this problem on my own. I've managed to get close I believe, but I think I don't quite understand Craft's relationships.

Basically, I have a related projects section on my site. I'm allowing the user to select the related projects with an Entries tag within my matrix. I would then like to compare their selected Entries with projects already added to a Structure - then output attributes that exist only in the Structure.

This is as far as I've gotten:

My Structure Content

```
{% for entry in craft.entries.section('homePageBanners').limit(3) %}
    {% for block in entry.banner.limit(3) %}

        {{ block.client }}
        {{ block.bannerImage }}

    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

My Matrix Entries Block:

```
{% for entry in block.projectsEntry %}
    <a href="{{ entry.getUrl() }}">{{ entry.title }}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

I'm not sure how to compare them & pull content based on what the user selects. I looked into relatedTo(), but didn't have much luck with that.

If that's not clear, I can try to be more specific -- please go easy on me, I'm pretty new to Craft.

EDIT:

Maybe this will help clarify
    {% for entry in block.projectsEntry %}

```
 {% for project in craft.entries.section('homePageBanners').limit(3) %}
  {% set relatedProjects = craft.entries.section('homePageBanners').relatedTo(project) %}
   {% for project in relatedProjects %}
    <a href="{{ project[0].getUrl() }}">{{ project[0].title }}</a>
   {% endfor %}
  {% endfor %}
 {% endfor %}
```

Comment: Still no luck with this unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I totally understand your issue, but give this a try in your Matrix code:

```
{% for entry in block.projectsEntry %}
    <a href="{{ entry[0].getUrl() }}">{{ entry[0].title }}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

Are you getting any errors in devMode?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am not getting any return errors. I edited my original post to help clarify